# Sending e-mails in JAVA EE 6

Tags: java, email, java-ee-6

I'm developing a Java EE 6 application deployed on glassfish, I keep reading tutorials about how to send emails but they seem either outdated or too complicated. I was hoping that may be in this specification there's a rather simple way to send mail since so many things have become so much simpler.
Can you point me in the right direction or may be show me some sample code?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can utilize [apache commons email](http://commons.apache.org/email/userguide.html) or if you are using Spring then use [spring mail](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/mail.html). There is always [JavaMail](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/index-138643.html) if you don't want to use any of the wrapper libraries and a [code sample](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=144) on it.

All of these links have code examples.

Comment: does glassfish include a smtp server or any service to send mail? Or do I have to set one up separately?

Comment: You will need to either use your school or work smtp server. I have never used Dumbster but sounds like a good one to use. Kudos to James for providing that link.

Answer (score 0):

The JEE App Server should provide the email resource. The only think you need to do is lookup the resource (I suppose it is configured) and send the email.

```
//Mail  Resource injection not working on wildfly 10
//@Resource(lookup = "java:/futuramail")
private Session mailSession;

@Asynchronous
@Lock(LockType.READ)
    public void sendMail(String recipient, String subject, String text) {
        try {

            InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
            mailSession = (Session) ic.lookup("java:/futuramail");
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
            Address[] to = new InternetAddress[]{new InternetAddress(recipient)};
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, to);
            message.setSubject(subject);
            message.setSentDate(new Date());
            message.setContent(text, "text/html");
            //message.setText(text);
            Transport.send(message);
            System.out.println("mail sent");
        } catch (MessagingException me) {
            me.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NamingException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MailProcessor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: On my Wildfly 10.1.0.final , Mail resource Injection works perfectly either using lookup or name attributes